# SqlDataReader (in an assembly) returning different datatypes compared to sp_help

Tags: c#, sql, clr, sqlclr

I have a custom assembly that returns the column information for whatever query is thrown at it. While I was going through & double checking the values, it appears that a few of the 'DataTypeName' values returned from GetSchemaTable() are a bit off of what sp_help is returning for 'Type' on the same query. This looks to be exclusive to decimal and numeric fields.

For reference, here is the code behind the assembly:

```
using System;
using System.Linq;
using System.Data;
using System.Data.SqlTypes;
using System.Data.SqlClient;
using Microsoft.SqlServer.Server;

public class StoredProcedures
{
    /// <summary>
    /// example of sending a tabular result and a message through SqlPipe.
    /// </summary>
    [SqlProcedure]
    public static void CLRExec(SqlString query)
    {
        DataTable schema = null;
        SqlContext.Pipe.Send(DateTime.Now.ToString() + " -- " + query.ToString());
        using (SqlConnection connection = new SqlConnection("context connection=true"))
        {
            string sQuery = query.ToString();

            // Create the record and specify the metadata for the columns.
            SqlDataRecord record = new SqlDataRecord(
                new SqlMetaData("ColumnName", SqlDbType.NVarChar, 100),
                new SqlMetaData("DataTypeName", SqlDbType.NVarChar, 100),
                new SqlMetaData("ColumnSize", SqlDbType.Int),
                new SqlMetaData("NumericPrecision", SqlDbType.Int),
                new SqlMetaData("NumericScale", SqlDbType.Int));

            connection.Open();

            SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand(sQuery, connection);
            SqlDataReader reader = command.ExecuteReader();

            schema = reader.GetSchemaTable();

            //Mark the begining of the result-set.
             SqlContext.Pipe.SendResultsStart(record);
            foreach (DataRow col in schema.Rows)
            {
                record.SetString(0, col.Field<String>("ColumnName").ToString());
                record.SetString(1, col.Field<String>("DataTypeName").ToString());
                record.SetInt32(2, col.Field<int>("ColumnSize"));
                record.SetInt32(3, col.Field<short>("NumericPrecision"));
                //if column is type int, scale of 255 = 0 else 255 = ''
                record.SetInt32(4, col.Field<short>("NumericScale"));

                // Send the row back to the client.
                SqlContext.Pipe.SendResultsRow(record);
            }

             SqlContext.Pipe.SendResultsEnd();
        }
    }
}
```

Here's a screenshot demonstrating the differences: https://i.stack.imgur.com/Nd82X.png

I don't feel like it's that big of an issue since the precision and scale seem to be correct everywhere. However, I plan on using this assembly to allow users to build custom data-sources on the front end and want to make sure this won't cause anymore headache further down the line.

Comment: From T-SQL Reference: "Decimal and numeric are synonyms and can be used interchangeably."

Comment: Incidentally. You should use `ExecuteReader(CommandBehavior.SchemaOnly)`. You don't need to execute the query just to get metadata. And SqlCommand and SqlDataReader should be put on a using block because they implement IDisposable

Comment: @JesúsLópez Thanks for the help and I appreciate the advise! This is my first time even touching C# so I really have no idea what I'm doing.